# Firebird/Lazarus SQL View with select iif?

Tags: sql, view, firebird, lazarus, iif

I want to select rows from a table with a calculated field defined with the select query.

For example, my select could be:

```
Select FirstName, 
       LastName, 
       iif(Cast('Now' as date)-BirthDate<18, 'Minor', 'Major') as StatAge 
from TableUsers;
```

With Lazarus, I want to filter on StatAge.

I tried my query directly on my database with a tool.

I can filter with a Where on my query like that :

```
Select * 
from (
  Select FirstName, 
         LastName, 
         iif(Cast('Now' as date)-BirthDate<18, 'Minor', 'Major') as StatAge 
  from TableUsers
) 
Where StatAge = 'Minor';
```

But it doesn't work on lazarus with `TSQLQuery.Filter` I can filter on other fields and no problem. My problem is only with this calculated field.

So maybe I have to create a View on my database? But I've got an error when I tried to add my view with my query.

My SQL Code to create the view is below, and the error is

> "Unsuccessful metadata update can't format message 8:132 -- message file C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\firebird.msg not found.

I've never seen that in the past:

```
CREATE VIEW "TSTT_SELECT" ("ID_SENT", "Eng", "Char", "ID_STT", "Order", "Stat", "StartSAE", "RetSAE", "ArrSAE", "StartSHE", "RetSAE") 
AS 
Select "EMAIL_SENT"."ID", "EMAIL_SENT"."COMMANDE_TABLE", "EMAIL_SENT"."CHAR", "TSTT"."ID", "TSTT"."ORDER", iif("TSTT"."RETOUR_PREV" Is Not Null AND ("TSTT"."RETOUR_PREV">cast('Now' as date)), 'En retard', iif("TSTT"."Depart_SAE" Is Null, 'A expedier', iif("TSTT"."Depart_SAE" Is Not Null And "TSTT"."Arrivee_SHE" Is Not Null And "TSTT"."Depart_SHE" is null,'Chez le STT',iif("TSTT"."Depart_SHE" Is Not Null, 'Au depart STT', iif("TSTT"."Arrivee_SAE" Is Not Null, 'Récéptionné', ''))))) as "Statut", "TSTT"."Depart_SAE", "TSTT"."RETOUR_PREV", "TSTT"."Arrivee_SHE", "TSTT"."Depart_SHE", "TSTT"."Arrivee_SAE" 
from "EMAIL_SENT" 
   Left join "TSTT" on "EMAIL_SENT"."ID" = "TSTT"."ID_EMAIL";
```

Comment: you here mix two different problems: usage of `TSQLQuery.Filter` in FPC/Lazarus and creating views in Firebird. Those are different problems and about different programs. W.r.t. the Firebird - you seem to not install Firebird Client on the system. So there is no `firebird.msg` file near `fbclient.dll` - thus it can not provide you with error text. Find the msg file of the latest Firebird version and put it near the client dll that your program uses. P.S. also it may be better to use `CURRENT_DATE` var, https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-now.html

Comment: The error seems to be code 336068740 which is Table ... already exists. Which suggests you already have a view (or table) called `TSTT_SELECT`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel how do you know the code? grepped FB sources for 8:132 ?

Comment: @Arioch'The Error codes are `0x14000000 | (facility << 16) | (number & 0xFFFF)`, here facility is 8 and number is 132. Although I could also have searched in `src/msgs/message2.sql` on `8, 132`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `BirthDate` field is of type `Date`, if you use a utility like FlameRobin to execute firstly
the SQL you quote in your q and then the following SQL, you'll see that there there is an error in your SQL.  The error is that your `iff` returns a number of **days**, not **years**
so that the return value of the `iff` is wrong.  I'm not very familiar
with Firebird SQL so in my version have "fixed" this by multiplying
18 by 365 which of course ignores leap years.

```
Select FirstName,
       LastName,
       Birthdate,
       iif(Cast('Now' as date)-BirthDate<18 * 365, 'Minor', 'Major') as StatAge ,
       Cast('Now' as date)-BirthDate
from TableUsers;
```

Then I set up the minimal Lazarus project set out below, and it works fine,
including correctly filtering on the edFilter.Text expression.

Code:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    edFilter: TEdit;
    SQLConnector1: TSQLConnector;
    SQLQuery1: TSQLQuery;
    SQLTransaction1: TSQLTransaction;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  public
  end;

  [...]

  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    if not SQLQuery1.Filtered then
      SQLQuery1.Filter := edFilter.Text
    else
      SQLQuery1.Filter := '';
    SQLQuery1.Filtered := not SQLQuery1.Filtered;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    edFilter.Text := 'STATAGE = ''Minor''';
    SQLQuery1.Sql.Text :=
    'Select '#13#10
    + '  FirstName, '#13#10
    + '  LastName, '#13#10
    + '  Birthdate, '#13#10
    + '  iif(Cast(''Now'' as date)-BirthDate<18 * 365, ''Minor'', ''Major'') as StatAge , '#13#10
    + '  Cast(''Now'' as date)-BirthDate '#13#10
    + 'from TableUsers2;';

    SqlQuery1.Open;
  end;
```

Comment: Has this helped with your filtering problem?

Answer (score 0):

So,
I solved my problem with IBX4Lazarus component. This is a specific component for Interbase/firebird.

I used it in the past because firebird wasn't integrated by lazarus. Now, we can connect to firebird DB with standard lazarus component, but we can see that there are some problems... So I'm going to work only with IBX components for a better optimisation.

My problem is solved by using IBX4Lazarus : [www.mwasoftware.co.uk](https://www.mwasoftware.co.uk)

Comment: Hmm.  I am not sure I believe that your problem is "solved".  I have found an error in your Q which means that it cannot possibly work correctly, if my assumptions are correct.  I have a minimal project written in Delphi which works fine (filtering included).  I'll try re-writing it for Lazarus and post it as a new answer in the next hour or so, assuming it works.